# Raspberry Pi Start python script during boot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, python3, autostart

I have a Raspberry Pi which has a I2C 16x2 display screen. The screen simply say Welcome.

Problem: I would like for this script to run as soon as the Raspberry Pi is turns on with power.

I added the following command to my rc.local file sudo python /path/to/file
It will start automatically however it takes 45 seconds or more before the script runs.

Is there a way to start a python script or display on the screen as soon as power is on the Raspberry Pi or within 10 second of turning on?

Answer (score 0):

Systemd can start a service conditionally relative to another service by enforcing dependent relationships you specify in the service's unit file.  I had a similar problem as you where I needed to execute a script in a certain order, so I created a systemd service for it and started my custom service **AFTER** another service.

Sounds harder than it is.  Not terribly complicated and worth knowing about for future reference.

This is a (2) step Process:

### Step 1: Analyze the order services rise-up

Before you can specify a conditional relationship to start your script (*as a service*) either ***before*** or ***after*** in a service's unit file, you need to understand when & how the services rise-up.

The below command will graph services start-up with their respective times from power-on:

```
sudo systemd-analyze plot > /home/pi/services-startup.svg
```

Open the file with *Image Viewer* and you can see from system startup when services start.

Other tools for understanding dependencies between services:

```
sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain
sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain someServiceName.service
tree /etc/systemd/system
```

### Step 2: Create Custom Service for Your Script to Enforce Order Dependency

There are many directives which can be used to create dependent relationships between services, `Before` and `After` being the more obvious ones:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=

### Example Unit File:

I had a script that emails the IP address of a headless Pi that was failing due to the order the script (run as a service) was executing.  I went through the above analysis and created the following unit file configuration to execute my script as a ***oneshot*** service.  It achieved this by waiting to start my custom service until **AFTER** the service `motion` completed:

```
cat <<EOF> /etc/systemd/system/email-camera-address.service
[Unit]
Description=Email IP Address of Camera on Boot
Requires=network-online.target
After=motion.service
[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=$PATHSCRIPTS/email-camera-address.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/email-camera-address.service
systemctl enable email-camera-address.service
```

The full script the above taken from can be found [HERE](https://github.com/open-ipcamera/open-ipcamera/blob/master/service-emailCameraAddress.sh):